# Importing typescript modules from a separate directory without navigating the relative path?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have the following this typescript file `src/main/ts/hello.ts` containing:

```
    export function hello() {
      return 'Hello World!';
    }

    export default hello;
```

The corresponding test is in `src/test/ts/hello.spec.ts`.  It imports `hello` like this:

```
    import hello from 'hello';
```

IIUC the below configuration should allow me to import `hello.ts` within the test without using a relative path.

```
    {
        "include": [
            "src/main/ts/**/*.ts"
        ],
        "exclude": [
            "node_modules"
        ],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "*", "src/main/ts/*"
            ]
        },
        "compilerOptions": {
            "experimentalDecorators": true,
            "noImplicitAny": true,
            "moduleResolution": "node",
            "target": "es6"
        }
    }
```

However I'm still getting this error:

```
src/test/ts/hello.spec.ts(1,19): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'hello'.
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Hi, @Ole, you should check TS modules https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `baseUrl` and `paths` property in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
   "include": [
     "src/main/ts/**/*.ts",
     "src/test/ts/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "exclude": [
     "node_modules"
   ],

   "compilerOptions": {
     "experimentalDecorators": true,
     "noImplicitAny": true,
     "moduleResolution": "node",
     "target": "es6",
     "baseUrl": ".",
     "paths": {
       "*": [
         "*", "src/main/ts/*"
       ]
     }
   }
 }
```

Documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#base-url

Comment: Hi @Saravana - I updated the question with the the results I'm getting.  Does it look like I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: See my updated answer. 1. `baseUrl` and `paths` should be inside `compilerOptions`. 2. Your `include` is missing the path to test files.